# face detection is a bit slow. how do i improve the speed and efficiency and also how do i save the faces?

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, face-detection

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s, img = cam.read()

winName = "Movement Indicator"
cv2.namedWindow(winName, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

while s:
    cv2.imshow( winName,img )

    s, img = cam.read()
    hc = cv2.CascadeClassifier("foo.xml") #xml file for detection
    faces = hc.detectMultiScale(img)
    for face in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(
            img, (face[0], face[1]), (face[0] + face[2], face[0] + face[3]),
            (255, 0, 0), 3
        )

    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        cv2.destroyWindow(winName)
        break
```

Comment: For saving the image use cv2.imwrite(filename, img ) .
I guess if you use c++ , it could be more faster. In your case, why dont you reduce cv2.waitkey(10) to cv2.waitkey(3) to make it more faster

Comment: yea, that'll give 7 milliseconds ;)

Comment: @berak
How does the rectangle function work? I mean how are you giving the points by specifying `body[0], body[1]` and `(body[0]+body[2], body[0]+body[3])`?

What does the bodies array contain exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html

Two easy things you can try to accelerate your detections (both at the cost of less accuracy):

- You can increase the scaleFactor, the default value is 1.1, you can try 1.2 or 1.3, this means that at each scale in the multi scale scanning it downsamples the image by a larger factor.
- You can set a relatively large minimum face size, for example (64,64), this means it will stop searching for smaller faces, thus saving time. You can also experiment with maximum face size, if you know more or less what size the face will have in your scene.

Answer (score 0):

that's really all your code ? iirc, it only works on grayscale

- try trading speed for accuracy, and use a lbpcascade instead of the haar one
- cv2.imwrite("myface.png", img[ face[1]:face[1]+face[3], face[0]:face[0]+face[2] ] ); should save the face roi

Comment: this part of the code only detects faces from webcam.
and it does work for coloured images as well.
but how do i know if the same face is datected again ?

Comment: aka face *[recognition](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html)* ?